# How to get last array element while Projection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-java-driver

I have following document structure (This is dummy document for understanding purpose)

```
{ 
    "id" : "p1245", 
    "Info" : [             
        { 
            "cloth_name" : "ABC", 
            "cloth_type" : "C"
        },
        { 
            "cloth_name" : "PQR", 
            "cloth_type" : "J"
        },
        { 
            "cloth_name" : "SAM", 
            "cloth_type" : "T"
        }
    ] 
},
{ 
    "id" : "p124576", 
    "Info" : [             
        { 
            "cloth_name" : "HTC", 
            "cloth_type" : "C"
        }
    ]
}
```

From these document I want to project the "cloth_type", so I tried following java code

```
    DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("id", 1);
    fields.put("ClothType","$Info.cloth_type");
    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields);
    List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(project);
    AggregationOptions aggregationOptions = AggregationOptions.builder().batchSize(100).outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.CURSOR).allowDiskUse(true).build();
    Cursor cursor = collection.aggregate(pipeline, aggregationOptions);
    while (cursor.hasNext()) 
    {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
```

(I don't want to use "$unwind" here)

and get following output:

```
{ "id" : "p1245" , "ClothType" : [ "C" , "J" , "T"]}
{ "id" : "p124576" , "ClothType" : [ "C"]}
```

If there are multiple "cloth_type" for single id, then I want only the last `cloth_type` from this array.
I want something like, e.g. if there is array of "`ClothType`" [ "C", "J", "T"] then I want to project only [ "T"] i.e last element of array.
Is there any ways to achive this without using "$unwind".

Comment: Why don't you want to use `$unwind`?

Comment: Do you want to put the last element retrieval into the aggregation query itself? Why don't you do in in Java?